# How to take over previous URL via Facebook login on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm implementing Omniauth Facebook login on Rails app.
Also I'm trying to implement friendly forwarding.
I mean, once you log in via Facebook and sign up by devise, the app should be back to previous URL.

For the purpose, I used session variable. But once the app redirect to Facebook, all session variable has gone.

Would you tell me how to recall previous URL? Thanks in advance.

[Appendix]
Here's my code.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    session[:url_before_signup] || "/#{I18n.locale}"
  end

  def store_location
    session[:url_before_signup] = stored_location_for(:user)
  end

class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def facebook
        set_locale
        @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

        if @user.persisted?
            # if you check session[:url_before_signup], it always turn to nil
            sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
            set_flash_message(:notice, :facebook_login_success) if is_navigational_format?
            set_flash_message(:notice, :facebook_login_success_and_regist_data) if is_navigational_format? && @user.completed_at.nil?
        else
            session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `request.referrer` in controller?

Comment: Ah, slightly different. Our website is like this. Article page -> Log in page -> FB Auth -> Article page. In this case, FB auth erase session. Then, our app can't take over request.referrer. All I have to take over is Article page url.

Comment: Otherwise try save that in cookies/local storage to avoid using session related stuff?

Comment: Well, one realistic solution is to use database. But it needs long code. It feels like redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with my application.So I applied a monkey patch.
What you can do is, you can store your previous url in a session before going to the login page. Then after sign in you can check whether this session variable is present or not,if present you can then redirect to that url.

Example:

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     after_filter :store_location
      def store_location
        # store last url as long as it isn't a /users path
        if (request.fullpath != "/sign-in") || (!request.fullpath  =~ /\/users/)
          session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
        end
      end
    end




 class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
      if session[:previous_url].present?
        return_to_url = session[:previous_url]
      end
    end
 end
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I described above, I did same thing. But when facebook sdk returns to call back, session variable is gone away. So what should I do?